# Jasper charts - Undefined length exception

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I have 16 bar charts in my jasper report.

when I loaded it the first time , I had no issues and all 16 of them loaded.

However ,on consecutive runs, I get this error . The nodata section has been added in the jrxml and I have added this as per my reading on the internet but have added no success

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
```

[image]

Any ideas on this?

Comment: IIRC this error used to occur in an older version when the chart had no data.  If you upgrade to a recent version the error should go away, but you'd see an empty chart.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved after I mapped the parameters inside the chart. This was missed. Also, adding a no data condition to the chart helped in showing a no data scenario in a user friendly manner